# What does "stationary system" mean in the assumptions for Little's Law?

Tags: queueing-theory

More specifically, how does Little's Law continue to hold, for example, for a single bank teller that takes 10 minutes to process a client, and the clients arrive at the rate of 20 per hour (i.e., one every 3 minutes).  Won't the line keep increasing, leading to the nonexistence of a "steady state" number of requests in the system?

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems the average service time is so great that the queue almost surely grows without limit, then this is not a stationary system and there is no long-term average number of customers in the queue and no average time that a customer spends in the system

So if [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) is something like *"the long-term average number $L$ of customers in a stationary system is equal to the long-term average effective arrival rate $λ$ multiplied by the average time $W$ that a customer spends in the system"* then you should say that the terms in Little's Law would be meaningless (or perhaps that $L$ and $W$ would be infinite) in your case

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought.  So, for Little's Law, in the version you cite, does "stationary" mean that the system should be able to process the requests so that there is no boundless growth of a queue?

Comment: @avs: yes: boundless growth is not stationary (it might be possible to imagine a system that did not have boundless growth but was also not stationary)

Comment: thanks much for clarifying.